# Total of each week data to be displayed in Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a Table looking like this. Now I need to display the total weekwise for Total test and cycle run after each week row. Any help?

Currently the table looks like this:

```
Week  Project     OS        TotalTests  #cycle of run 
    1     P1     Windows       0              0
          P2     Linux,UFO     4799           1

    2     P3     Windows       234           5
```

Expected Table should be like :

```
 Week  Project     OS        TotalTests  #cycle of run 
    1     P1     Windows       0              1
          P2     Linux,UFO     4799           1
                   Total:      4799           2

    2     P3     Windows       234            5
                   Total:      234            5
```

Here is the code:

```
success: function (data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    var Total = 0;
                    var TotalCycle = 0;
                    var oldValue = data[data.length - 1].WW,
           c = 1;
                    for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        let $tr = $('<tr/>');
                        if (i == 0 || oldValue != data[i - 1].WW) {
                            $tr.append("<td rowspan=\"" + c + "\">" + "WW - " + data[i].WW + "</td>");
                            c = 1;
                            if (i > 0) oldValue = data[i - 1].WW;
                        } else {
                            c++;
                        }
                        $tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Project + "</td>");
                        $tr.append("<td>" + data[i].OS + "</td>");
                        $tr.append("<td>" + data[i].TotalTests + "</td>");
                         Total = Total + data[i].TotalTests;
                        $tr.append("<td>" + data[i].CycleRun + "</td>");
                         TotalCycle = TotalCycle+ data[i].CycleRun; 

                        $('#GraphTable').prepend($tr);
            }
        }
```

Comment: your expected table looks like ? ... can you provide a demo view ?

Comment: @MinarMnr my bad. Please check the edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going backwards in your loop in this case makes more complicated to later find the position to put each totals row. Here you have my approach going forward...

https://jsfiddle.net/rigobauer/959pthuk/

A piece of advice, handle and modify jQuery objects and DOM elements is slower than javascript arrays or strings, so consider using that for your loops and minimize the DOM manipulation. For example, instead of...

```
for (...) {
    let $tr = $('<tr/>');
    $tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Project + "</td>");
    $tr.append("<td>" + data[i].OS + "</td>");
    .....
    $('#GraphTable').prepend($tr);
}
```

... use ...

```
let rows = [];
for (...) {
    let row = '<tr>' +;
              '<td>' + data[i].Project + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + data[i].OS + '</td>';
    .....
              '</tr>';
    rows.push(row);
}
$('#GraphTable').prepend(rows.join(''));
```

Depending on the size of the loop, it can be way more faster.

And remember to cast your strings to numbers when you need to sum...

```
Total = Total + parseInt(data[i].CycleRun);
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sugestions. I will definitely use this :) I tried out the code you suggested for my question but it isn't working as per requirement. I have added a demo fiddle here. Please check. https://jsfiddle.net/j7usutbj/2/

Comment: Oh.. I see what happens... Your're going backwards to get the info of the json object (any reason for that?). This is going to be a problem, because when you finish with one week, you'll have to find the position for the total row... I'll try to reformulate going forward with the json object...

Comment: because its week wise. I need to display WW just 1s for each week . You can see the dummy table examples i have given in the question

Comment: Here you have my approach (still need to add the week rowspan, but you can start checking out this): https://jsfiddle.net/rigobauer/959pthuk/

Comment: yeah looks good now. Let me take care of rowspan then. Thanks a lot :) Please update the answer

Comment: Now it also has rowspan. Let me know how it goes.